# How to add captcha to publish widget

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, admin, spam

I want to add a captcha challenge to the "publish post" widget in "add new post" to prevent spam posts. This is because my site is open to registrations and posting.

Could someone please suggest how I would go about this as I am not a programmer and wouldn't know where to start?

Would a plugin be able to do this? If so how would i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the Contributor role for your site users. Then when they write a new post it will have to be reviewed by an Administrator before it gets published.
Have a look at this link also ->  http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: I have looked into this but it would be too time consuming to review every article. The way I want it to work is that the first 1 or 2 posts have to be approved then they get author status. I need the captcha to prevent spammers from getting through that approval stage then submitted rubbish after that. Is there a way to do what I propose? I usually use drupal for sites and this is my first time using wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

GravityForms.com has the ability to auto-post on a blog with or without admin approval.